# Dynamicly loading css files for popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have a page where I want onclick to show users kind of popup styled with css. 
Every popup is html fetched via ajax from php backend and most of them need different css file. I can`t include all css files in the begining, because some overwrite others, so I have to dynamicly load specific css for specific html. 
So I typed this

> file1: 
>   link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/popup1.css" 
>   
>   file2: 
>   link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/popup2.css" 
>   etc.
>   
>   at the begining of every html popup.

this works, most of the time, but sometimes it looks like css is ignored and the html is displayed at the bottom of the page unstyled.

I tried load the css file and append it to head before fetching html like this:

```
var css = document.createElement("link"); 

        $(css).attr('type', 'text/css');

        $.get('/css/popup1.css', function(result){

            $(css).html(result);
            $('head').append(css);

            $.get('/fetchHtmlPopup.php', function(data){
                $(cotainer).html(data);
                $(container).fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });
```

This seemed to work, but actualy this way fails sometimes too and I still have no idea what causes this code somethimes to work ok, sometimes to fail.
What bothers me the most is the fact that both solutions work, sometimes they don`t I can`t find a specific action to cause this.

Anybody has any idea what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing could be because of the order in which the css file & the dialog html is loaded. The behaviour could be different based on if css was loaded first or the HTML.

There are two ways of solving this problem.

1. It is better to have a parent container to the pop-up and let the style on parent container control the style of the inner elements. Sample code is below,

   green > leftBox { .... }
       blue > leftBox { .... }

   ...
2. The other way is to apply the style using jquery to the necessary elements. this approach can be taken only if the amount of styling to be applied is very less.

Comment: they are about 600 rows CSS each, so applying style with js is not OK in this case. I`ll try to include all css files, make them class specific and change only the class of the container. We`ll see. Thanks for the advices

Answer (score 0):

try adding an error handler and check the error message to find out your issue

```
$.get(
url: "/css/popup1.css", 
success: function(result){
            $(css).html(result);
            $('head').append(css);

            $.get({
                url: "/fetchHtmlPopup.php",
                success: function(data){
                        $(cotainer).html(data);
                        $(container).fadeIn("fast");
                    },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                });
       },
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                } );
```

you can certainly clean the above code a little bit.